# Check if value obtained from equation slightly wrong because of double precision limitation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, precision

I calculate an algorithm which operates some big matrices together. The result of 25 iterations is

```
 43094433924714.60  42305389712997.10   42051869142057.30   41857066081162.10   41709555393330.50   41567289549908.10   41445508409456.40   41351519393007.90   41285939671446.50   41246739458582.20   41227637000953.50   41221374361160.30   41222070832734.30   41225683762693.20   41229940202366.40   41234197403025.10   41238259341968.60   41242214489820.80   41246250974730.60   41250072955515.30   41253409784178.00   41256148996999.60   41258526183343.50   41260749335391.20   41262757761836.80
```

I found it is weird as I expect them to be monotonically decreased. I try to find the reason and realize these numbers are 14 exponents with 2 mantissa which is more than `double-precision` format. How can I check if this weird trend comes from just wrong calculation in `python`?

The equation and simplified data example is down below:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import rand

eps = 1e-6
matrix = rand(5000, 1300, density=0.25, format="csr")*1e7
V = matrix.todense() + (np.random.rand(5000,1300) + 1.0)
W = np.zeros((5000, 100), int) + eps
np.fill_diagonal(W, 1, wrap=True)
W = np.dot(W,np.diag(1/sum(W)))
H = np.random.rand(W.shape[1],V.shape[1]) + 1.0
ONES = np.ones(shape=(V.shape[0],V.shape[1]))
cost = []
for it in range(25):
    Wt = W.conj().T
    H = np.multiply((H / np.dot(Wt,ONES)),(np.dot(Wt,(V/(np.dot(W,H)+eps)))))
    cost.append(np.sum(np.multiply(V,np.log(V/(np.dot(W,H)+eps))) - V + np.dot(W,H)) + np.sum(H))

print cost
```

Is it possible to use `decimal()` to proof (for very accurate calculation) just at the end? I think it should have some better ways.